# Integrate $\int \sin^3(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried to solve $\int \sin^3(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}\,dx$ by setting it equal to 
$$\int \cos^{1/2}(x)\left(1-\cos^2x\right)\sin(x)\,dx $$
and then making $u=\cos(x)$ and $du=-\sin(x)$. I ended up with
$$\frac{-2\cos^{3/2}(x)}{3} + \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2} + C$$
but the book's answer is
$$\frac{2\cos^{7/2}(x)}{7} + \frac{2\cos^{3/2}(x)}{3} + C$$

Could you give a hint as to what I'm doing wrong? [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocw1c.jpg) my full work.

Comment: Can you actually provide the work you've done so we can see where you might've went wrong?

Comment: Just posted a picture.

Comment: I really like this question! So I went ahead and proposed a few minor improvements (nothing semantically pedantic). If you feel these edits detract from the quality of your thread, then always feel free to roll them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\int \sin^3 x \sqrt{\cos x} \, dx
&= \int (1 - \cos^2 x) \cos^{1/2} x \sin x \, dx \\
&= \int (\cos^{1/2} x - \cos^{5/2} x) \sin x \, dx \\
&= \int -(u^{1/2} - u^{5/2}) \, du \\
&= \frac{2}{7} u^{7/2} - \frac{2}{3} u^{3/2} + C \\
&= \frac{2}{7} \cos^{7/2} x - \frac{2}{3} \cos^{3/2} x + C. \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\int(u^{1/2}-u^{2+1/2})du=?$$

Comment: I ended up with $\int u^{\frac1 2} - u du$...

Comment: @Molly, $$u^{1/2}(1-u^2)=?$$

Comment: Yeah, sorry! And I had a negative outside the integral too.

Comment: @Molly, u r right!

Comment: Oh... so where did I go wrong then?

Comment: @MollyTaylor, $$a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}\ne a^{mn}$$ in general

Comment: @mollytaylor the correct multiplication is $u^{1/2}-u^{2+1/2}=u^{1/2}-u^{5/2}$

Answer (score 1):

$\int \sin^3x \sqrt {\cos x}\;dx=\int (u^2-1)\sqrt u\;du$ where $u=\cos x.$

Now $(u^2-1)\sqrt u\;=u^{5/2}-u^{1/2}$. This seems to be where you erred. It integrates to $\frac {1}{1+5/2}u^{1+5/2}-\frac {1}{1+1/2}u^{1+1/2}.$